# how to add a list with different product sizes in opencart?

Tags: opencart

i'm have to make a webshop with opencart.

The person who i am making this website for, wants to sell cooking pans, with different sizes.

so, if you click on a product, there has to be a list with the different sizes of the cooking pans, and different prizes.

Is this possible ?

many thx !

Comment: You need to use the `Options` tab options in Admin Product page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This, of course, is possible :-)

All You need to do is to set the product options. In Opencart administration, go to tab `Catalog` and select the `Options` item. Crete an option, let's call it `Pan sizes` and choose a form field for it - whether a *radio buttons* or *select* would be OK for it. After saving You would have to add `Pan sizes` option's values - here You can set all the possible sizes of the pans. When You are finished You can assign that option and set the concrete possible size options in the product detail -> open up the desired product, choose the `Options` tab and add an option - `Pan sizes`. Then add all the relevant sizes options and adjust the pieces count, price that is added or subtracted as well as other options there and hit Save at the end.

You should be done.

Comment: Sorry, usually there are 5+ people answering questions for OpenCart, don't know why nobody answered sooner. But still it's better to have the answer here for future (same/similar) questions. ;-)

Comment: i mean: My comment is al little late :p

Comment: Ahh, OK, no problem then :-)